# Sum of invertible matrices proof

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have two square matrices, $A$ and $B$. 
Assume that $A + B$ is invertible. Would that mean that $A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ is invertible too?

Comment: $A+B$ invertible does not imply $A$ is invertible...

Comment: Do we assume that $A$ and $B$ are invertible?

Answer (score 13):

For the question to make sense, we assume that both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.

We know then that the matrices $A^{-1},B^{-1},$ and $A+B$ are all invertible.  It follows that the same must hold for their product
$$
A^{-1}(A+B)B^{-1} = A^{-1}AB^{-1} + A^{-1}BB^{-1} = B^{-1} + A^{-1}
$$
That is, the matrix $B^{-1} + A^{-1} = A^{-1} + B^{-1}$ must be invertible.

Comment: nice explanation

Answer (score 3):

consider very basic exmaples as pointed out by David Holden, $A = 0$ and $B =I$ then $A + B = I$ is invertible. But how can you make sence of $A^{-1}$?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe the implication exists. Consider matrices $A = \left( \begin{array}{c}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)$ and $B = \left( \begin{array}{c}
0 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)$. It is clear that $A + B$ is invertible, but $A^{-1}+B^{-1}$ is undefined as $B^{-1}$ does not exist. However, if you add the condition that $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ both exist, I am not sure.

Comment: In the future, you should read other answers before submitting your own.  In your answer, which was submitted about 20 minutes before any others, you repeat what GA316 stated in his answer, then remarked on your uncertainty about that which I state in my answer.

Comment: I was writing my answer before those comments were posted. It just so happened that by the time I posted my answer comments with similar content had been posted.